# Rails caching "random" query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to display a random user with the following in the controller:

```
@random_user = User.where(is_admin: false).order('RAND()').first
```

But each time I refresh the page, the same user gets shown each time. How can I tell rails to re-run this query on each refresh of the page?

**Update**

Embarrassing fix: the problem was a default_scope in the model. Fixed by using `.unscoped` in the query.

Answer (score 1):

you can use or try `sample` `@random_user = User.where(is_admin: false).sample` this will return random user.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking the database to

1. sort ALL users (this might be a lot of work), then
2. selecting the first.

Better might be:

1. select a random number less than the number of selectable users.
2. Then grab that user.

e.g.

```
scope = User.where(is_admin: false)
count = scope.count
user  = scope.offset(rand(count)).limit(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

As i understand you are using some sql database.

To fetch random record you can use different ways, all of them working nice in different situation.

1) Fast enough in small tables

```
User.where(is_admin: true).limit(5).order("RAND()").first
```

2) Fast in middle-size tables (`offset`)

```
User.where(is_admin: false).limit(1).offset(rand(User.count)).first
```

3) Just for example

```
User.where(is_admin: false).sample
```

**Update**

I think one of the important thing, which you must keep in mind that every `orm` query will be translated into `sql`. So you must analyze what happens `under the hood`.

PS: I don't understand how question title is related to question ?)

Answer (score 0):

This is embarrassing: the problem was a default scope in the model.

Doing an `unscoped` query fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method, if you are using MSSQL, is that you could 
    ORDER BY NEWID()
which generates a nearly-random GUID.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `take` method:

`@random_user = User.where(is_admin: false).take`

Cheers